# How can I fetch duplicate contacts in my table view when show button pressed?

Tags: ios, swift

this is how try to find duplicates in my function

```
let keys = [CNContactIdentifierKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)]
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)
var contactsByName = [String: [CNContact]]()
```

after I call do/catch

```
do {
    try self.contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
        guard let name = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName) else { return }
        contactsByName[name] = (contactsByName[name] ?? []) + [contact]
    }
} catch let err {
    print("error:", err)
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: "How can I..." doesn't describe the issue your having. Could you clarify what it is that doesn't work?

Comment: I want to append duplicates in anther table view... excuse for my English :( How can I do it

Comment: Why not use the values property of your dictionary as the data source for that table? let dataSource = contactsByName.values

Comment: let duplicates = contactsByName.filter { $1.count > 1 }
        print(duplicates), the output return me ["Fabio Dolci": [<CNContact: 0x7fcce67370a0.... the exact name of duplicate, How can I format it?

Comment: It's an array, "[<CNContact: 0x7fcce67370a0...", access each item an format them individually